# What does the code on the back of this photo mean?

Tags: metadata

This is on the back of a photo and I'm just wondering what the numbers mean

```
01680010081001 Line [65] Qty-(1)
7039551 F33 WalMart.com
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify date from code on back of print photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94352/identify-date-from-code-on-back-of-print-photo)

Comment: @MichaelClark it doesn't look like a duplicate as the code format is very different.

Comment: Go to your local Walmart and ask them what the coding means.

Comment: @DrewNoakes  As the answers to the other question inform, the formats and what information each field represents can be changed by the user of the machines, such as the Fuji Frontier which was a very popular system. Saying since the the format is not the same it can't be from the same type of machine is like saying the same kind of typewriter could not have produced two different letters because they use different words and paragraph formatting.

Comment: @MichaelClark I read the other answer and it was very interesting. I interpret _Users have some leeway in assigning what information is printed_ as meaning only minor changes. This output is clearly significantly different.

Comment: @AlexNightingale, do you have more examples from other photographs? Comparing a few images, even from the same batch, might reveal something useful.

Comment: @DrewNoakes The machines were/are flexible enough to print whatever the user wants. They came from the factory with a default profile, but rare was the machine that was left with that profile intact. Especially larger customers, such as Walmart, had the setup altered to their own specification at the time. Different regions within Walmart may have had different setups. Over a couple of decades, I've seen the prints I had done at Walmart (which as far as I know used Fuji exclusively from the mid 1980s until they stopped developing film in -store) with many different setups...

Comment: ... , even when prints were printed several months/years apart on the same machine in the same store. The user could choose from a wide variety of information to include or not and choose how it was arranged. I used to deliver the machines in the 1990s (but did not set them up - we were just transportation service though we did have to place it in the spot in the photo-lab area where it was to be installed).

Answer (score 1):

I used to get Kodak Advantix photographs printed out with text like that. Usually it encoded the date/time of printing, some camera settings, customer order number and serial number of the machine used to do tbe printing.