# Can anyone determine the date or just year of this photo from the code on the back?

Tags: date

Have this photo and wondering when it was taken/printed. From summer house that’s been in the family for over 50 years. Can anyone determine the date or even just the year from the code? Not even sure if that’s possible, just hoping! If anyone could help I’d really appreciate it.Code below:

<No.3A> 040 23+00 NNNNN-07AU 3750

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I decode information on back of printed photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94352/how-can-i-decode-information-on-back-of-printed-photo)