# Date on the back of a developed photograph

Tags: date

Would any one have an idea of a year on either of these two stamps on the back of 2 photographs.

(1)
QSS 27 58 N N N 2 2 printed on Kodak paper.

(2)
05 41+00 NA1NN+ 12 015 printed on Fujicolor paper

Thanking You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I decode information on back of printed photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94352/how-can-i-decode-information-on-back-of-printed-photo)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, when development dates are printed on the back of photographs, they are printed in a user friendly way: DEC97 for instance. While it had become a pretty common piece of information to find on the back of photos in the late 90s, those dates were rarely present in the earlier years of photography.

When reading the codes your provided, rather than  actual development dates, this looks more like correction codes used in photo processing during those days to optimize the photo output. Correction codes where typically logged on the back of photos so that the customer could get a similar print with a similar output if wanting a copy of a photo. Correction codes typically recorded machine used / colours setting / exposure settings etc.