# I'm trying to approximately date some photos

Tags: prints

I have 2 printed photos which I am approximately trying to date. Either year taken or was printed. The code on the back of the first one is Blacks 03702 NNN1A and is slightly smaller than standard photos,the other is Shopper's [15]072 0161 1 N11NNN2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The codes on the rear of your prints are not date codes. See this question: [How can I decode information on back of printed photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94352)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I decode information on back of printed photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94352/how-can-i-decode-information-on-back-of-printed-photo)